# How to make a worldborder that expands every in-game day at dawn?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to make a world with a world border that increases 2 blocks every in game day when the sun rises using command blocks. How would I accomplish this?

I don't completely understand commands so please be really detailed in how to do this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get a slowly expanding world border in Minecraft?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/181937/how-to-get-a-slowly-expanding-world-border-in-minecraft)

Comment: @MrLemon  dont think it is a duplicate because that tells you how to make  it expand with time and will not take into sleeping i just want it to expand every time the sun rises

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both of these solutions require you to have set up your worldborder first, and to know the location of your spawn chunks (the chunks around your world spawn). They need to be built in the spawn chunks so that they are always loaded.

#### Simple solution

Place a daylight sensor on top of a command block with the following command:

```
/worldborder add 2
```

Make sure the daylight sensor is exposed to daylight. The major downside here is that it is not exactly hidden.

#### Hidden solution

For a server or just general asthetics, it might be good to hide the command blocks deep underground at bedrock level. Unfortunately, this is a little more complicated, but totally doable.

Create a scoreboard objective called `daytime` using

```
/scoreboard objectives add daytime dummy
```

[As pointed out by Skylinerw on the Minecraft forums](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-discussion/redstone-discussion-and/command-blocks/2468502-command-block-help?comment=4), daytime does not actually reset to 0 every day. Sleeping in a bed advances the daytime forward to a multiple of 24000 instead of setting it to 0. To make this work, we create a second objective and use it to store a number (24000) in a fake player called "#DAYLIGHT" (The "#" is illegal in player names, making this unique).

```
/scoreboard objectives add MATH dummy
/scoreboard players set #DAYLIGHT MATH 24000
```

Now, create a [setblock or fill-clock](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/227011/how-do-i-make-a-setblock-or-a-fill-clock/) running the following commands.

```
/time query daytime
/stats block <x> <y> <z> set QueryResult @a daytime
/scoreboard players operation @a daytime %= #DAYLIGHT MATH 
/execute @p[score_daytime=1000,score_daytime_min=1000] ~ ~ ~ worldborder add 2
```

where `<x> <y> <z>` are the coordinates of the command block with the first command (relative coordinates using `~` work).

Comment: i cant get your hidden solution to work i dont know what im doing wrong. So far I have a setclock with 3 command blocks around the redstone block with your 3 commands in them and when i do /time set 1000 nothing happens

Comment: @RNH good comment, I just saw that I actually forgot something. You have to replace `<x> <y> <z>` with the coordinates for the first command block.

Comment: I did that and still the world border did not move

Comment: @RNH Hm... it worked for me when I tested it. Then again, I used `time set 990` to test it. Try that, and if it works, set the execution time to 1010 instead. Also, use `scoreboard objectives setdisplay sidebar daytime` to check if the scoreboard updates correctly

Comment: On the third command block i get this message underneath the command "The entity UUID provided is in an invalid format" maybe that has something to with it not working

Comment: @RNH That's the error you get when the target selector doesn't resolve a valid target. NULL is not a valid UUID.

Comment: alright so when i add the sidebar it says my name and then 0 so it must not be updating or something but in the chat it says "storing Querystat results in daytime on @a"

Comment: "Unfortunately, this is a little more complicated, but totally doable." - couldn't you simply hook up the daylight sensor to an inverter, the command block on the inverter output, and the whole thing encased in bedrock? Covered daylight sensors are inverted IIRC.

Comment: @Random832 Yeah, *always*. As in, it’s not reacting to dawn in any way, because it can’t see the dawn.

Comment: @KRyan That's not what the wiki says.

Comment: @Random832 Ah, I misread your comment. The wiki, at least, confirms your idea.

Comment: Its ok i got a fix for my idea http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-discussion/redstone-discussion-and/command-blocks/2468502-command-block-help

Comment: @RNH great find. I incorporated it into the answer.

Answer (score 5):

First place a daylight sensor with a comparator infront of it, with the comparator facing out of the daylight sensor. Then put a command block as the output of the comparator. The redstone should look like following:

[image: Redstone]

Then, inside the command block, type:

```
/worldborder add 2
```

How this works is that the daylight sensor will activate each day and when it activates, it will give an input to the comparator which will then execute the command inside the command block and add a distance of 2 to the world border.

Comment: Duh. You answered faster than me. Edit: I edited my answer and let him know that your take on daylight sensors can be better.

Comment: @ardaozkal Thank you, but it seems he chose you anyways.

Comment: I used your method in the end

Comment: @RNH Well, you should accept the method that you used and worked for you.

Answer (score 3):

**Plan 1: (hard&redstone way, no big differences with Plan 2) (not tested)**
First of all, you must do a 1 day loop with redstones. And next off, when you connect them to the command block, you must add /worldborder add 2 1 (2 = 2 blocks, 1 = 1 seconds to open) to it.

**Plan 2: (easy way) (tested and works)**
Put a Daylight Sensor, connect it to a command block, add /worldborder add 2 1 (2 = 2 blocks, 1 = 1 seconds to open) in command block.

***Note:*** Plan 2 might not work, see [CommandFox](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/112980/commandfox)' answer for a better take of this plan.

**Plan 3:  (tested and works)** *(world will grow slowly, a new block everymidday)*
A minecraft day is 20 minutes. 1200 seconds. So just use this code in console: /worldborder add 2xdays-you-want 1200xdays-you-want. So making this work for 1000 days would be /worldborder add 2000 1200000.

Also if you are mapping, I recommend adding another command block to let the player know that world grew.

Comment: will the daylight sensor still work if i have it underground

Comment: @RNH unfortunately and AFAIK no.

Comment: ok so i tested it and the daylight sensor will work underground but it will turn on at night instead of day